# How to structure data on Geoserver for forecast data

Tags: netcdf, geoserver, wms, forecast

I'd like to use Geoserver to serve forecast data. My forecasts are in Netcdf files, one file per 12 hours, from few years period of time. I want to expose Netcdf files download and also run WMS and CSW services.

For now I'm trying GUI actions, like adding `workspace`, `store` and `layer` from Netcdf files. I know I could also add files using REST requests.

How should be data structured in Geoserver terms, what would be my `store` and `layer`? As for now, single `store` is made from single Netcdf file. Then single `layer` I create is one of the Netcdf variables. Now, in `layer preview`, single layer seems to have only 1 time. 
And then, should another Netcdf file from another time be another `store`, with this file as data source?
How should I name the layers then? Default layer naming suggests names derived from Netcdf variable, so I'd have to name it like i.e.

`workspace_name:VARIABLE_YYYYMMDDHH`

to avoid collision with another variable `layer` from different Netcdf. 
Or is there some other way, maybe is it possible to add multiple Netcdf files to single store, or access variables from different files in single layer?

Comment: This is not such an obvious thing in Geoserver, and requires some knowledge of Geoserver features. I don't see the reason for negative score, especially without comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a time series enabled image mosaic, fortunately GeoServer provides exactly that [module](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html#data-imagemosaic). It also provides a [tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) on how to set it up.

You should also check out the [section on NetCDF files](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html) if you have not already done so.

Comment: Thanks, I have to read up on it. There are still some unclear parts, how to set all configuration files properly. So far following some examples doesn't work, but I hope i'll figure it out. Initially I skipped image mosaic probably because of documentation part, where it says, that it is about joining granules (term which I associated with satellite data) and it is mentioned, that image mosaic _could be used to assemble a set of overlapping geospatially rectified images into a contiguous image. It could also be used to create a montage of photographs such as a panorama._

Comment: if you have further questions, you will probably get a better response on http://gis.stackexchange.com